# Search database when needle has a longer string than in the haystack

Tags: php, mysql

This is my needle (sample): **I am a long text so long - this is here too**

In my haystack (Table in DB) I have multiple rows of text. One of which is this: **I am a long text so long**

The **- this is here too** is appended before my process begins.

My question here is how do I search for my needle in the DB using SQL code?

I don't want to fetch everything inside the table and do a foreach + stristr to find my needle as it would be wasteful.

Also, I can not explode my needle since some of the text may contain **-** as well.

I have tried using LIKE:

```
 LIKE "%I am a long text so long - this is here too"
 LIKE "%I am a long text so long - this is here too%"
 LIKE "I am a long text so long - this is here too%"
```

But nothing matches **I am a long text so long**

Is there another way for me to achieve this using SQL?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at MySql Full Text Search function. It could return search results by relevancy.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Thanks! I had to do another filter after this to get the data I want though but it still led me to the right place.